# Hyper V unable to activate in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtualbox

I have a host machine with the following specs:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits 8GB RAM

and then I set up an virtual machine by Orable VirtuaBox with the following specs:
Windows Server 2008 R2 64bits 4GB RAM

In the VM, Hyper V was unable to activate due to virtualization has been disable in the VM.

after couple of search, I found that VirtualBox not allow to create another nested virtual machine.

Is there any work around if I wanted to work in multiple virtual machine environment?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm voting to close this as too localised. There really is no good reason to run nested virtualization products.

Comment: Is hardware virtualization enabled in the guest settings? To activate it in the guest, it will need to be enabled in the BIOS as well.

Comment: As you found in your searching, VirtualBox doesn't allow nested virtualization.  If you need it, get a virtualization platform that supports it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no workaround as Hyper-v needs access to the VT instructions that are not presented by virtualbox.  I believe that the latest version of virtualbox will run on a hyper-v host however.

Answer (score 3):

VMware Workstation also allows for nested virtualization.

I set up an entire virtual platform (SAN, two ESXi nodes and a vCenter Server on a 2008 R2 instance) for demonstration purposes.